# Binding in nested XAML WPF not evaluated

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, livecharts

I have a nested WPF View where I pass Objects through to the inner layers via Dependency Properties.

My outer XAML layer passes data into `RetentionChartControl.ChartParams`:

`<local:RetentionChartControl ChartParams="{Binding PeakRow.Chartparams[0], RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:PeakrowChartGroupControl}}}"></local:RetentionChartControl>`

In my most inner layer I have the following XAML code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DryLab.Peakmovement.RetentionChartControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DryLab.Peakmovement" 
             xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Name="uc"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
   
    
    <Grid>
        <lvc:CartesianChart x:Name="cc" Series="{Binding ChartParams.Seriescollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:RetentionChartControl}}}" >
            <lvc:CartesianChart.DataTooltip>
                <lvc:DefaultTooltip SelectionMode="OnlySender" />
            </lvc:CartesianChart.DataTooltip>
            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                <lvc:Axis  Foreground="Black" Title="{Binding ChartParams.TitleAxY, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:RetentionChartControl}} }" LabelFormatter="{Binding ChartParams.Formatter, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:RetentionChartControl}}}">
                </lvc:Axis>
            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                <lvc:Axis  Foreground="Black" Title="{Binding ChartParams.TitleAxX, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:RetentionChartControl}}}" Labels="{Binding ChartParams.Labels, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:RetentionChartControl}} }"></lvc:Axis>
            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        </lvc:CartesianChart>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now the Binding for `<lvc:Cartesian Chart>` (From LiveCharts https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Basic%20Line%20Chart) is working, the ChartParams Variable is fully evaluated and i can Access the Seriescollection.

However if i look at the deeper nested `<lvc:Axis>` (via LiveVisualTree) the `Title` Property is never evaluated.

What have i missed? Why cant i bind to ChartParams from within `<lvc:Axis>`?

Any help is appreciated, will post further code if necessary.

**Edit:**
I should add, that when the application is running, and I touch my `Axis.Title` in Xaml, it reevaluates and then shows the results as espected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that the `Axis` element is not added to the visual tree the moment the bindings are resolved. All visible elements that are a child of the chart's underlying `Canvas`, are added later (long time after the chart control's `FrameworkElement.Loaded` event was raised). Therefore data bindings that bind e.g. `Axis` or `Separator` etc. to their visual parent using `RelativeSource` will point to nowhere (unless you set the binding after the relevant target elements are added to the `Canvas` (requires C# instead of XAML) by observing the `CartesianChart.Content.LayoutUpdated` event, but I recommend against this).

The recommended solution is to bind to the `DataContext` instead.

You can either set the `UserControl` itself as its own `DataContext`:

**PeakrowChartGroupControl.xaml.cs**

```
partial class PeakrowChartGroupControl : UserControl
{
  public PeakrowChartGroupControl()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;
  }
}
```

**PeakrowChartGroupControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="DryLab.Peakmovement.RetentionChartControl">
    <Grid>
        <lvc:CartesianChart x:Name="cc" Series="{Binding ChartParams.Seriescollection}">
            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                <lvc:Axis Title="{Binding ChartParams.TitleAxY}" 
                          LabelFormatter="{Binding ChartParams.Formatter}" />
            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                <lvc:Axis Title="{Binding ChartParams.TitleAxX}" 
                          Labels="{Binding ChartParams.Labels}" />
            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        </lvc:CartesianChart>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

---

Or alternatively e.g., in case the `UserControl.DataContext` is already set to something else, you can explicitly set the charts `DataContext` to e.g., the `ChartParams` property of `RetentionChartControl`:

**PeakrowChartGroupControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="DryLab.Peakmovement.RetentionChartControl">
    <Grid>
        <lvc:CartesianChart DataContext="{Binding ChartParams, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:RetentionChartControl}}" 
                            Series="{Binding Seriescollection}">
            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                <lvc:Axis Title="{Binding TitleAxY}" 
                          LabelFormatter="{Binding Formatter}" />
            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                <lvc:Axis Title="{Binding TitleAxX}" 
                          Labels="{Binding Labels}" />
            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        </lvc:CartesianChart>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: thanks Bionic , passing my parameters directly to `DataContext` was all it needed.